# Using a vintage button bulb saver be used for CFL or halogen lamps?

Tags: incandescent

Recently got a big box full of vintage tools and electrical stuffs. I came across this strange looking (seems vintage by its looks) button device. Its the first time I came across it.I googled and read that it can be of two types thermistor and diode type. The later actually uses one half of cycle to increase filament life.

So, will it do any good with other forms of lamps like halogen, CFL etc? I'm just curious, thats all:) Also does the button need to be installed in a particular direction?
[image]

Comment: May work with halogen, but CFL and LED are likely to have issues with it : for example they may have switching supplies, which can boost the current to compensate for reduced voltage, remaining full brightness...

Comment: OMG that goes back a long way to a time when bulbs were expensive and it was worth the cost to extend the life. Then bulbs got ten a penny and it was cheaper just to replace the bulb. As Brian says, likely less than effective on modern driven bulbs which may not even start.

Comment: Just curious, when where these used like in which years?

Comment: @RahulSalin up to the early 80's I think. At least that's when they were promoted https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1981/05/31/light-bulb-energy-buttons-watt-about-saving-38/acb0c2c3-c3a6-4e67-abdb-0072dc20f578/?utm_term=.dd10aa33ef10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diode type bulb saver is just a halfwave rectifier .It will not be good on a CFL .Half wave rectifiers like this draw DC  current of the AC mains and lots of harmonics of even and   odd order                .The power Authoraties in most countries will not permit this these days .Do keep your antiques because they represent a bygone era and the NTC      thermistor ones could be useful because they do reduce inrush current  .

Comment: I just searched and the one from Bulb miser was the thermistor version. The one in my possession is the diode type. I just checked with continuity/diode tester and it gives 578 in one direction. Yes, I'll definitely add this to my collection of vintage items. :)